# Sending email via mysql bash

Tags: mysql, email

I have a query that sends the results to an email. I would like not to send an email if the query has NO results. How can i do that ?

heres the code

```
mysql -umy -hmysql1.com -P2 -pmysq <<<" Select * from Data.data "| mail -aFrom:test@test.com -s 'test' test@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every task can be done easily in a single command pipeline. Trying to force it into a one-liner can make it hard to code and hard to maintain.

Feel free to write some statements in a script:

```
result=`mysql -umy -hmysql1.com -P2 -pmysq -e " Select * from Data.data "`
if [ -n "$result" ]
then
    echo "$result" | mail -aFrom:test@test.com -s 'test' test@gmail.com
fi
```

The `-n` test is for strings being nonzero length. Read http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html for more details on that.

---

Re your comment:

The statements I showed above are things you could type at the command-line in bash. Bash supports variables and "if/then/else" constructs and a lot more.

Writing a bash script is easy. Anything you can type at the command-line can be in a file. Open a text editor and write the lines I showed above. Save the file. For example it could be called "mailmyquery.sh" (the .sh extension is only customary, it's not required).

Exit the text editor. Then run:

```
bash mailmyquery.sh
```

And it runs the statements in the file as if you had written them yourself at the command-line.

Voilà! You are now a shell script programmer!

Comment: I'm not sure how to run this code in a script? I'm just using a bash script

Comment: I tried using a PHP script, but I still cant get the code to work

Comment: iam getting this error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: I just tested the script and it works fine as I wrote it. Sorry, I have no way of  knowing what you did differently.

Comment: I got it working, I think it was an issue with p and c into the text editor . Thank you for your help  ...Happy new year :)

Comment: Happy New Year! Remember that it is customary on Stack Overflow to thank people for help you by upvoting their answer, and/or clicking the "accepted answer" checkmark.